# In a NodeJs code with (Array)Buffers, native readUInt16BE is used but my context is a browser so i want to use use DataView.getUint16 instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, dataview, arraybuffer

I came across a JPEG parsing function in Node.js that I'm attempting to adapt for use in a browser environment. The original code can be found [here](https://github.com/evidentpoint/buffer-image-size/blob/master/lib/types/jpg.js#L39).

The original code uses Node.js' Buffer class. As i would like to use it it for a browser environment we have to use the `DataView.getUint16(0, false /* big endian */)` instead of  `buffer.readUInt16BE(0) /*BE = big endian */`

Interestingly, DataView is also available in NodeJs, so the result could be cross environement.

Here what I found so far :

- Introducing a variable `j` starting from 4 helps get the correct offset for the first iteration, as the buffer 4 first bytes are sliced :

```js
  let j=4 // match the buffer slicing above
```

- Adding + 2 to j for next reading does not help getting the correct offset for next iteration despite the buffer being sliced of exactly two more bytes

```js
    j+=2; // match the buffer slicing below ( i + 2 )
    buffer = buffer.slice(i + 2); // Buffer is sliced of two bytes, 0 offset is now 2 bytes further ?
```

Here is the function with logging added

```js
function calculate (buffer) {

  // Skip 4 chars, they are for signature
  buffer = buffer.slice(4);
  let j=4 // match the buffer slicing above
  let aDataView=new DataView(buffer.buffer);
  var i, next;
  while (buffer.length) {
    // read length of the next block
    i = buffer.readUInt16BE(0);
    console.log("i="+i,"read="+aDataView.getUint16(j,false));
    j+=2; // match the buffer slicing below ( i + 2 )
    // ensure correct format
    validateBuffer(buffer, i);

    // 0xFFC0 is baseline standard(SOF)
    // 0xFFC1 is baseline optimized(SOF)
    // 0xFFC2 is progressive(SOF2)
    next = buffer[i + 1];
    if (next === 0xC0 || next === 0xC1 || next === 0xC2) {
      return extractSize(buffer, i + 5);
    }

    // move to the next block
    buffer = buffer.slice(i + 2);
  }

  throw new TypeError('Invalid JPG, no size found');
}
```

Actual result on [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/JPEG_example_flower.jpg):

```bash
node .\start.js 
i=16 read=16 # Seems to be the correct offset
i=91 read=19014 # Wrong offset
i=132 read=18758
```

My debbuging steps are so far:
Installed buffer-image-size from npm
`npm install buffer-image-size --save`
Wrote start.js as the following

```js
var sizeOf = require('buffer-image-size');
const fs = require('fs');

fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync("flowers.jpg");
var dimensions = sizeOf(fileBuffer);
console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
```

Edited **"node_modules\buffer-image-size\lib\types\jpg.js"** adding mentioned lines and logging

Do you have any hint about

- **Why adding 2 to `j` does no helps to get the correct offset.**
- **How to get the same algorithm without slicing the buffer over and over**

I appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: You need to **either** increment `j` **or** move the `buffer` to a new `.slice()`, not both at once

Comment: Oh wait you also have the problem that your `DataView` is on the original `buffer.buffer`, not the reassigned one.

Comment: And what is the type of `buffer` in the first place? The variable name suggests that it's an `ArrayBuffer` but accessing `buffer.buffer` means it's more likely to be a `Uint8Array` (or other typed array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, avoid to both advance offsets and re-slice the buffer, it only gets confusing. I would write

```
function calculate(typedArray) {
  const view = new DataView(typedArray.buffer, typedArray.byteOffset, typedArray.byteLength);
  let i = 0;
  // Skip 4 chars, they are for signature
  i += 4;

  while (i < view.byteLength) {
    // read length of the next block
    const blockLen = view.getUint16(i, false /* big endian */);

    // ensure correct format
    // index should be within buffer limits
    if (i + blockLen > view.byteLength) {
      throw new TypeError('Corrupt JPG, exceeded buffer limits');
    }
    // Every JPEG block must begin with a 0xFF
    if (view.getUint8(i + blockLen) !== 0xFF) {
      throw new TypeError('Invalid JPG, marker table corrupted');
    }

    // 0xFFC0 is baseline standard(SOF)
    // 0xFFC1 is baseline optimized(SOF)
    // 0xFFC2 is progressive(SOF2)
    const next = view.getUint8(i + blockLen + 1);
    if (next === 0xC0 || next === 0xC1 || next === 0xC2) {
      return extractSize(view, i + blockLen + 5);
    }

    // move to the next block
    i += blockLen + 2;
  }

  throw new TypeError('Invalid JPG, no size found');
}
```

Notice that this code, which is a straightforward translation of [the source](https://github.com/evidentpoint/buffer-image-size/blob/92d014e394c05542c320c94c7d7f2b23ad449330/lib/types/jpg.js#L20-L57), is slightly confusing and buggy:

- `i` does not point to the start of the segment, but rather two bytes into the segment (after the marker)
- the code skips the first dynamic segment (which, admittedly, [is required to be an APP0 segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) anyway)
- the code assumes all segments to have a variable length specified in their header, and ignores standalone markers as well as fill bytes
- the code may cause `RangeError` exceptions from accessing bytes beyond the end of the buffer, as it only checks for the *past* block to be within limits

Comment: Thank you, Bergi! Your solution worked for my issue. I appreciate your help!

I had to edit view.length into view.bytelengh and edit extractSize to use wiew.getUint16 and it worked like a drop in replacement. Impressive.

I'm looking how increasing the offset by 2 was messing up, as the view was on the original buffer, thus not being affected by buffer slicing.

However i did not get it was needed to jump to next block using the blockLen.

I'm still working on my first version to be sure to understand any part of the loop but it feels great knowing it exists an already working version.

Comment: I had arrived to exactly the same algorithm as you indeed using your code as an example when i was stuck. I'm satisfied but I'm wondering why accessing to view.getUint8(pos + blockLen + 1) is not the same as buffer[pos + blockLen + 1].
I accepted your answer !

Comment: I think the problem with your original code was that `j` started at `4` but also `aDataView` was over `buffer.slice(4).buffer`